# Perfect tense vs present tense

Tags: grammar

I would like to learn about the difference in meaning of the following sentences.

> 1) The books **were** on the table since morning
>
> 2) The books **have been** on the table since morning

In which cases, each of them would be more appopriate to use?

Comment: Since you used "sir" and I am a girl, I don't think you would want me to answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

The word "since" has multiple meanings. With respect of the context in the statement mentioned, I am taking definition from Google, which says, "in the intervening period between (the time mentioned) and the time under consideration, typically the present."
Which means some ongoing active started in past and still going on. The sentence in question is bit ambiguous. I am assuming the books are still on the table. The the proper sentence formation would be, "the books are on the table since morning"
As far the second sentence is concerned, since present perfect continuous tense is used, it would be appropriate to use a verb following that. For instance, "the books have been lying on the table since morning". Thanks.